# Ubuntu stopped detecting my second monitor, and my lap top screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I got two new **Benq 27" monitors** last night, plugged them in and everything worked great.  Started by machine this morning, and it will not detect my second monitor, and if I unplug everything my laptop screen is now blank!  I have a **Dell G7** with Nvidia. Driver version `455.45.01-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`, **GeForce GTX 1660 Ti**
So it will only detect one monitor, it will no longer see my laptop screen, settings do not show an option for a second monitor, but it did last night, and Nvidia settings do not show a second monitor either, but it did last night.
I have now tried many "solutions" posted on here, but nothing is working.  Should I do a reinstall?
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

In the absence of the linux version 3 approaches, without using the command line, are suggested:

1st:
Installation of a prior nvidia driver on `Software and Updates` > `Additional drivers` > choose other nvidia driver version > reboot the laptop > if you don't see the second monitor go to the screen settings and check if the second monitor is selected as active.
If not working select another nvidia driver using the above procedure.

2nd:
Reboot the laptop and press `Esc` in order to enter the `GRUB` menu > select a prior version of the ubuntu kernel; example: `Ubuntu, with 5.X.X-XX-generic` > if you don't see the second monitor go to the screen settings and check if the second monitor is selected as active.

3rd:
Reboot the laptop > on the users login screen select `Configurations/ Options` > select `Wayland`